# CoreData: concurrency and relationship strong reference cycles

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm importing a chunk of data into CoreData, using a subclass of `NSOperation` to do so. The operation creates its own `NSManagedObjectContext` (with concurrency type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`) specific to the run method of the operation. During import, I need to create a relationship between an instance of `NSManagedObject` in the `NSOperation` object context (we'll call it Object A) and another object in another `NSManagedObjectContext` (Object B).

The relationship establishes successfully, but I'm running into a relationship strong reference cycle ([Apple docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001860-SW2)) that I can't seem to break **without compromising the integrity of the relationship**. Not breaking the cycle isn't fatal, but it causes a balloon in memory footprint during import that is unacceptable. Using `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` and setting `mergeChanges:` to `NO` (as is typically recommended for breaking relationship strong ref cycles) screws with the data; it doesn't save correctly, and in some cases doesn't save at all.

**How do you break relationship strong reference cycles when working with CoreData concurrently?**

Comment: Did you manage to solve this somehow? I have basically the same problem